# Castle Windsor - Why would I not want to use 'NoTrackingReleasePolicy' as default?

Tags: castle-windsor

I come from the StructureMap world, where it is never necessary to release resolved transient objects.

I see that Windsor by defauly keeps track of any resolved transient objects and therefore prevents them from being garbage collected until they are released (if they ever are released).

I found ***NoTrackingReleasePolicy*** in the docs, but it's usage is [discouraged](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Release-Policy.ashx).

Having to release any transient objects seems like going back in time to me.

I will use NoTrackingReleasePolicy in my app.

What trouble am I getting into by doing this? Or in other words why would I want to release objects manually instead of having the garbage collector handle that for me?

Comment: I recommend reading http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor.aspx before taking any decision about this. In a nutshell: if you have to worry too much about this, you're using the container the wrong way (be it StructureMap, Windsor, or any other container).

Comment: @Mauricio, thanks for the link. Was a very interesting read. In my case I am working from within the context of an asp.net mvc app, so it seems that I will not need to manually release any dependencies in the controllers.
I wonder though how it will work with Wcf Web Api which we are also using heavily. I don't think that the service classes will autom. get released when the web request ends. Will have to investigate that.

Comment: the WCF facility does that: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/tree/master/Facilities/WcfIntegration don't know about WebAPI specifically.

Answer (score 4):

Just so that question doesn't stay unanswered:

The matter is explained in the blogpost [linked](http://web.archive.org/web/20121031025300/http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor.aspx) by @mauricio scheffer in the comments.

Basically using NoTrackingReleasePolicy is going to lead to a lot of subtle problems, and if you architect your app right, with the default release policy, you don't have to worry about calling release explicitly in your code anyway.

Comment: Link is broken now